# Can't print my result outside of for loop in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, cycle

I'm very new to C# and this exercise has been bugging me for a bit. The basic idea is I get an input of a number of Pheonix and need to read body length, width and length of wing for each one in order to calculate the amount of years they live. I created a for loop to read all the parameters, but I just don't know how to post the result at the end without having it output after every cycle. For example I have an input of:

```
2 phoenixes:
P1:
Body length: 100
Body width: 50
Length of 1 wing: 30
Total years: 100 ^ 2 * (50 + 2 * 30) = 1100000
P2:
Body length: 150
Body width: 25
Length of 1 wing: 10
Total years: 150 ^ 2 * (25 + 2 * 10) = 1012500
```

-- And I'm supposed to get the output:

> 2 100 50 30 150 25 10 1100000 1012500.

Instead I get the output:

> 2 100 50 30 1100000 1012500 150 25 10 1100000 1012500.

How do I avoid this?

```
int pheonixamount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < pheonixamount; i++)
{
    List<double> pheonix = new List<double>(3);
    double bodylength = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    double bodywidth = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    double lengthof1wing = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    pheonix.Add(bodylength);
    pheonix.Add(bodywidth);
    pheonix.Add(lengthof1wing);
    double result = Math.Pow(bodylength, 2) * (bodywidth + 2 * lengthof1wing);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Just edited it in.

Comment: why don't you make a List for result outside your loop.

Comment: You are not really using that `List<double> pheonix`: for each iteration you create a new one, add some values and forget about it.

Comment: Instead of a list storing three values for every phoenix, you should create a `Phoenix`-class with the three properties and use a list of this class.

Comment: Do you know how to create/use a Phoenix class (with properties for BodyLength, BodyWidth etc)? Or is that still an "advanced topic" at this point of your learning curve?

Comment: @Hans Keﬆing I would still consider it an advanced topic.

Comment: @bbleonfire, did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

It's right time to declare `Phoenix` class:

```
public class Phoenix {
  public Phoenix(double bodyLength, 
                 double bodyWidth, 
                 double lengthWidth) {
    if (bodyLength < 0) 
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(bodyLength)); 
    else if (bodyWidth < 0) 
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(bodyWidth)); 
    else if (lengthWidth < 0) 
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(lengthWidth)); 

    BodyLength = bodyLength;
    BodyWidth = bodyWidth;
    LengthWidth = lengthWidth;
  } 

  public double BodyLength {get;}
  public double BodyWidth {get;}
  public double LengthWidth {get;}

  public double TotalYears {
    get {
      return BodyLength * BodyLength * (BodyWidth + 2 * LengthWidth);
    }
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    return $"{BodyLength} {BodyWidth} {LengthWidth}"; 
  }
}
```

Now let's read all phoenixes into a *collection* (`List<Phoenix>`):

```
 int pheonixamount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

 List<Phoenix> phoenixes = new List<Phoenix>();

 for (int i = 0; i < pheonixamount; i++) {
   Phoenix bird = new Phoenix(
     double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),
     double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), 
     double.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
   );

   phoenixes.Add(bird);
 }
```

Finally, let's make a `report` based on `phoenixes` *collection*:

```
 string report = string.Join(" ",
   // 2 - number of phoenixes
   phoenixes.Count().ToString(),                                
   // phoenixes' exteriers (lengths and widths)
   string.Join(" ", phoenixes),                                 
   // phoenixes' total years - a pinch of Linq - Select
   string.Join(" ", phoenixes.Select(item => item.TotalYears)) 
 );

 Console.Write(report);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing result in same loop use another loop to print all values on console. 
As per your desired output you need to use `Console.Write()` not `Console.WriteLine()`

Your code create new list after each iteration in for loop, take that out of for loop

```
int pheonixamount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
List<double> pheonix = new List<double>(pheonixamount); //Use pheonixamount instead of constant value
List<double> resultList = new List<double>(pheonixamount); 
for (int i = 0; i < pheonixamount; i++)
{
    double bodylength = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    double bodywidth = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    double lengthof1wing = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    //Best way to store three values is to create new class, instead of storing in three different variables
    pheonix.Add(bodylength);
    pheonix.Add(bodywidth);
    pheonix.Add(lengthof1wing);
    double result = Math.Pow(bodylength, 2) * (bodywidth + 2 * lengthof1wing);
    resultList(result);
}

    //Print your pheonix values
   for (int i = 0; i < pheonixamount; i +=3)
   {
        //i, i+1, i+2 will give you bodyLength, bodyWidth, lengthof1wing respectively
        Console.Write(pheonix[i] +" "+ pheonix[i+1] +" "+ pheonix[i+2]);
   }

    //Print your result
   foreach (var item in resultList)
   {
        Console.Write(item);
   }
}
```